# How to set the derivative of a function to zero?

Tags: formatting

Maybe this is very basic, but I'm not getting it. I've googled around and searched here for an answer but I can't find it. I need to set `D[h[r], r]` equal to zero, so that when this is evaluated it shows that it's zero. I've tried doing:

```
Block[D[h[r], r], 0]
```

or even just

```
D[h[r], r] = 0
```

but this returns "tag is protected". Thank you for your help

Comment: Could you show Mathematica expressions instead of LaTeX?

Comment: Why do you need it to be zero? Is this to solve for something? Having the code would help.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify upvalues for any symbol. Try defining one on `h` as follows:

```
h /: D[h[r_], r_] := 0
UpValues[h]
```

As a result

```
D[h[x], x]==0
(* True *)
```

Comment: I tried this, but instead I used:
$$h_{rr}[r,\theta,\phi]$$
for h instead. I got the error "Argument at position 1 is expected to be a symbol. >>"
h is some function which will need to approximated later on in the code. One way I can make the entire output an approximation is by cutting off this derivative

Comment: No one can help with your error unless you give us the actual Mathematica expression that produced it.

Comment: Okay. I tried it this way:
`h11 /: D[h11, r] := 0`
`UpValues[h11]`
This returns
`TagSetDelayed::tagnf: Tag h11 not found>>`

Comment: I'm a bit stumped, because `h11 /: D[h11, r] := 0` doesn't give me an error. It's also not going to solve your problem though, because without underscores it will only match the literal expression `D[h11,r]`. You can add additional arguments to the answer I gave like this: `h /: D[h[r_, t_, p_], r_]:=0`