# Setting derivative of function equal to 0 at x=0 using UpValues

Tags: upvalues, calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to set the derivative of a function to zero at a specified point. This will act as an initial condition for an algorithm I'm writing: so I'm specifying the value of the function at x=0, and I'm specifying the value of the slope of the function at x=0. The function is u[n, x] and is unknown. The algorithm, based on Adomian decomposition method, will solve a nonlinear differential equation for this u-function.

```
Clear[u]
u /: D[u[n_, x_], x_] := 0
UpValues[u];
D[u[n, x], x] == 0
```

It gives the right output -- says it's True.

The problem I'm having is other queries say they are True when they shouldn't be:

```
D[u[n, x], 0] == 0 \\True
D[u[n, 0], 0] == 0 \\True
```

This is a somewhat duplicate of a question here, which is asked in a broader sense:
[How to set the derivative of a function to zero?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88622/how-to-set-the-derivative-of-a-function-to-zero)

Ideally, what should happen is based on modifying this line of code:

```
u /: (D[u[n_, x_], x_] := 0)/.x->0
```

The result would be:

```
(D[u[n, x], x] == 0)/.x->0 \\True
(D[u[n, x], x] == 0)/.x->5 \\False or indeterminate
```

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: Why not attach rules with `Derivative[]` instead? `u /: Derivative[0, 1][u][n_, x_] := 0`.

Comment: @J.M. In that case, I think `u` is too deeply nested in the expression, so it won't work. Every time I think `UpValues` is the solution to one of my problems, I get this error.

Comment: @march, thanks for trying it out; I currently do not have *Mathematica* on hand. I guess a simple `Derivative[0, 1][u][n_, x_] := 0` should have to suffice.

Comment: @J.M. Or, as I read it, `Derivative[0, 1][u][n_, 0] := 0`.

Comment: Thank you guys! Michael's advice worked. I did not know we could set derivatives equal to a number using := notation, but it makes sense.